# How do you get a kik profile picture for a given profile name?

Tags: kik

I'm trying to find a way I can get the URL for an image from a person's kik username. This user will provide their username. I want to run this on an iPhone so ideally a restful request would be best. But I've not seen any restful API for kik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps you......

```
http://cdn.kik.com/user/pic/[USERNAME]
```

e.g. http://cdn.kik.com/user/pic/teamkik

Comment: @arvin,@murum,@mark-beta this url seems to be working, but for first time it is getting old profile pic, it is taking a while to get the new pic. I saw few websites who get the profile pic immediately. I want to do that way...

Comment: @RavindraKumarChallagandla if you still need this, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer is not outdated you can get the profile picture URL using

```
https://ws2.kik.com/user/USERNAME
```

e.g. https://ws2.kik.com/user/KikTeam

This returns a JSON Response

```
{"firstName":"Kik","lastName":"Team","displayPicLastModified":1531418402837,"displayPic":"http:\/\/profilepics.cf.kik.com\/9wG3zRZW8sLxLnpmyOfwNE7ChYk\/orig.jpg"}
```

`displayPic` is the URL to the profile picture. Here is a Java Method I wrote to parse the response.

```
public static void getInformation(String username){
    String API = "https://ws2.kik.com/user/";

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(API + username).openConnection().getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
        String response = reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String firstName = jsonObject.getString("firstName");
        String lastName = jsonObject.getString("lastName");
        long displayPicLastModified = jsonObject.getLong("displayPicLastModified");
        String displayPic = jsonObject.getString("displayPic");
        System.out.printf("firstName: %s, lastName: %s, displayPicLastModified: %d, displayPic: %s\n",
                firstName, lastName, displayPicLastModified, displayPic);
    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now lets call it by using

```
getInformation("KikTeam");
```